# error about ACPI _OSC request failed (AE_NOT_FOUND)

Tags: 11.10, 64-bit

I have ubuntu server 11.10 64 bit

I see an error in kernel.log. This error comes out when the server reboot.

some port of grep APCI in kernel.log;

```
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.588605] pci0000:00: Requesting ACPI _OSC control (0x1d)
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.588667] pci0000:00: ACPI _OSC request failed (AE_NOT_FOUND), returned control mask: 0x1d
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.588746] ACPI _OSC control for PCIe not granted, disabling ASPM
```

Which hardware may be cause this error ?

```
root@www:# grep -r ACPI /var/log/kern.log
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.000000] BIOS-e820: 00000000bf780000 - 00000000bf798000 (ACPI data)
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.000000] BIOS-e820: 00000000bf798000 - 00000000bf7dc000 (ACPI NVS)
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.000000] ACPI: RSDP 00000000000fb1a0 00014 (v00 ACPIAM)
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.000000] ACPI: RSDT 00000000bf780000 00040 (v01 022410 RSDT1405 20100224 MSFT 00000097)
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.000000] ACPI: FACP 00000000bf780200 00084 (v01 022410 FACP1405 20100224 MSFT 00000097)
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.000000] ACPI: DSDT 00000000bf7804b0 0C359 (v01 A1279 A1279001 00000001 INTL 20060113)
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.000000] ACPI: FACS 00000000bf798000 00040
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.000000] ACPI: APIC 00000000bf780390 000D8 (v01 022410 APIC1405 20100224 MSFT 00000097)
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.000000] ACPI: MCFG 00000000bf780470 0003C (v01 022410 OEMMCFG 20100224 MSFT 00000097)
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.000000] ACPI: OEMB 00000000bf798040 00072 (v01 022410 OEMB1405 20100224 MSFT 00000097)
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.000000] ACPI: HPET 00000000bf78f4b0 00038 (v01 022410 OEMHPET 20100224 MSFT 00000097)
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.000000] ACPI: OSFR 00000000bf78f4f0 000B0 (v01 022410 OEMOSFR 20100224 MSFT 00000097)
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.000000] ACPI: SSDT 00000000bf798fe0 00363 (v01 DpgPmm CpuPm 00000012 INTL 20060113)
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.000000] ACPI: Local APIC address 0xfee00000
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.000000] ACPI: PM-Timer IO Port: 0x808
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.000000] ACPI: Local APIC address 0xfee00000
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x01] lapic_id[0x00] enabled)
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x02] lapic_id[0x02] enabled)
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x03] lapic_id[0x04] enabled)
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x04] lapic_id[0x06] enabled)
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x05] lapic_id[0x84] disabled)
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x06] lapic_id[0x85] disabled)
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x07] lapic_id[0x86] disabled)
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x08] lapic_id[0x87] disabled)
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x09] lapic_id[0x88] disabled)
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x0a] lapic_id[0x89] disabled)
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x0b] lapic_id[0x8a] disabled)
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x0c] lapic_id[0x8b] disabled)
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x0d] lapic_id[0x8c] disabled)
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x0e] lapic_id[0x8d] disabled)
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x0f] lapic_id[0x8e] disabled)
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x10] lapic_id[0x8f] disabled)
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.000000] ACPI: IOAPIC (id[0x01] address[0xfec00000] gsi_base[0])
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.000000] ACPI: IOAPIC (id[0x03] address[0xfec8a000] gsi_base[24])
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.000000] ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 0 global_irq 2 dfl dfl)
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.000000] ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 9 global_irq 9 high level)
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.000000] ACPI: IRQ0 used by override.
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.000000] ACPI: IRQ2 used by override.
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.000000] ACPI: IRQ9 used by override.
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.000000] Using ACPI (MADT) for SMP configuration information
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.000000] ACPI: HPET id: 0x8086a301 base: 0xfed00000
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.009507] ACPI: Core revision 20110413
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.499129] PM: Registering ACPI NVS region at bf798000 (278528 bytes)
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.500749] ACPI: bus type pci registered
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.502747] ACPI: EC: Look up EC in DSDT
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.503788] ACPI: Executed 1 blocks of module-level executable AML code
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.520435] ACPI: SSDT 00000000bf7980c0 00F20 (v01 DpgPmm P001Ist 00000011 INTL 20060113)
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.520863] ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.520990] ACPI: SSDT (null) 00F20 (v01 DpgPmm P001Ist 00000011 INTL 20060113)
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.521308] ACPI: Interpreter enabled
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.521366] ACPI: (supports S0 S1 S3 S4 S5)
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.521611] ACPI: Using IOAPIC for interrupt routing
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.522622] PCI: MMCONFIG at [mem 0xe0000000-0xefffffff] reserved in ACPI motherboard resources
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.554150] ACPI: No dock devices found.
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.554267] PCI: Using host bridge windows from ACPI; if necessary, use "pci=nocrs" and report a bug
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.555231] ACPI: PCI Root Bridge [PCI0] (domain 0000 [bus 00-ff])
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.588224] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Routing Table [\_SB_.PCI0._PRT]
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.588398] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Routing Table [\_SB_.PCI0.P0P1._PRT]
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.588451] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Routing Table [\_SB_.PCI0.P0P4._PRT]
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.588473] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Routing Table [\_SB_.PCI0.P0P6._PRT]
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.588492] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Routing Table [\_SB_.PCI0.P0P7._PRT]
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.588512] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Routing Table [\_SB_.PCI0.P0P8._PRT]
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.588540] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Routing Table [\_SB_.PCI0.NPE1._PRT]
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.588559] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Routing Table [\_SB_.PCI0.NPE3._PRT]
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.588579] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Routing Table [\_SB_.PCI0.NPE7._PRT]
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.588605] pci0000:00: Requesting ACPI _OSC control (0x1d)
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.588667] pci0000:00: ACPI _OSC request failed (AE_NOT_FOUND), returned control mask: 0x1d
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.588746] ACPI _OSC control for PCIe not granted, disabling ASPM
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.597666] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKA] (IRQs 3 4 6 7 10 11 12 14 *15)
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.598142] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKB] (IRQs *5)
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.598336] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKC] (IRQs 3 4 6 7 10 *11 12 14 15)
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.598810] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKD] (IRQs 3 4 6 7 *10 11 12 14 15)
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.599284] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKE] (IRQs 3 4 6 7 10 11 12 *14 15)
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.599762] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKF] (IRQs *3 4 6 7 10 11 12 14 15)
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.600236] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKG] (IRQs 3 4 6 *7 10 11 12 14 15)
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.600709] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKH] (IRQs 3 *4 6 7 10 11 12 14 15)
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.601931] PCI: Using ACPI for IRQ routing
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.628146] pnp: PnP ACPI init
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.628211] ACPI: bus type pnp registered
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.628417] pnp 00:00: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0a08 PNP0a03 (active)
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.628859] system 00:01: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0c01 (active)
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.628915] pnp 00:02: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0200 (active)
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.628951] pnp 00:03: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0b00 (active)
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.628975] pnp 00:04: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0800 (active)
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.629004] pnp 00:05: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0c04 (active)
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.629229] system 00:06: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0c02 (active)
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.629779] system 00:07: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0c02 (active)
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.629849] pnp 00:08: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0103 (active)
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.629901] pnp 00:09: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs INT0800 (active)
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.630030] system 00:0a: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0c02 (active)
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.630254] system 00:0b: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0c02 (active)
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.630304] pnp 00:0c: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0303 PNP030b (active)
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.630359] pnp 00:0d: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0f03 PNP0f13 (active)
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.630492] system 00:0e: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0c02 (active)
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.630986] system 00:0f: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0c01 (active)
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.631078] pnp: PnP ACPI: found 16 devices
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.631135] ACPI: ACPI bus type pnp unregistered
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.726291] ACPI: Power Button [PWRB]
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.726452] ACPI: Power Button [PWRF]
Dec 5 09:08:51 www kernel: [ 0.726527] ACPI: acpi_idle yielding to intel_idle
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.000000] BIOS-e820: 00000000bf780000 - 00000000bf798000 (ACPI data)
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.000000] BIOS-e820: 00000000bf798000 - 00000000bf7dc000 (ACPI NVS)
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.000000] ACPI: RSDP 00000000000fb1a0 00014 (v00 ACPIAM)
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.000000] ACPI: RSDT 00000000bf780000 00040 (v01 022410 RSDT1405 20100224 MSFT 00000097)
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.000000] ACPI: FACP 00000000bf780200 00084 (v01 022410 FACP1405 20100224 MSFT 00000097)
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.000000] ACPI: DSDT 00000000bf7804b0 0C359 (v01 A1279 A1279001 00000001 INTL 20060113)
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.000000] ACPI: FACS 00000000bf798000 00040
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.000000] ACPI: APIC 00000000bf780390 000D8 (v01 022410 APIC1405 20100224 MSFT 00000097)
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.000000] ACPI: MCFG 00000000bf780470 0003C (v01 022410 OEMMCFG 20100224 MSFT 00000097)
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.000000] ACPI: OEMB 00000000bf798040 00072 (v01 022410 OEMB1405 20100224 MSFT 00000097)
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.000000] ACPI: HPET 00000000bf78f4b0 00038 (v01 022410 OEMHPET 20100224 MSFT 00000097)
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.000000] ACPI: OSFR 00000000bf78f4f0 000B0 (v01 022410 OEMOSFR 20100224 MSFT 00000097)
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.000000] ACPI: SSDT 00000000bf798fe0 00363 (v01 DpgPmm CpuPm 00000012 INTL 20060113)
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.000000] ACPI: Local APIC address 0xfee00000
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.000000] ACPI: PM-Timer IO Port: 0x808
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.000000] ACPI: Local APIC address 0xfee00000
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x01] lapic_id[0x00] enabled)
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x02] lapic_id[0x02] enabled)
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x03] lapic_id[0x04] enabled)
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x04] lapic_id[0x06] enabled)
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x05] lapic_id[0x84] disabled)
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x06] lapic_id[0x85] disabled)
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x07] lapic_id[0x86] disabled)
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x08] lapic_id[0x87] disabled)
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x09] lapic_id[0x88] disabled)
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x0a] lapic_id[0x89] disabled)
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x0b] lapic_id[0x8a] disabled)
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x0c] lapic_id[0x8b] disabled)
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x0d] lapic_id[0x8c] disabled)
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x0e] lapic_id[0x8d] disabled)
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x0f] lapic_id[0x8e] disabled)
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x10] lapic_id[0x8f] disabled)
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.000000] ACPI: IOAPIC (id[0x01] address[0xfec00000] gsi_base[0])
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.000000] ACPI: IOAPIC (id[0x03] address[0xfec8a000] gsi_base[24])
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.000000] ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 0 global_irq 2 dfl dfl)
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.000000] ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 9 global_irq 9 high level)
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.000000] ACPI: IRQ0 used by override.
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.000000] ACPI: IRQ2 used by override.
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.000000] ACPI: IRQ9 used by override.
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.000000] Using ACPI (MADT) for SMP configuration information
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.000000] ACPI: HPET id: 0x8086a301 base: 0xfed00000
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.009505] ACPI: Core revision 20110413
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.499203] PM: Registering ACPI NVS region at bf798000 (278528 bytes)
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.500819] ACPI: bus type pci registered
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.503121] ACPI: EC: Look up EC in DSDT
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.504162] ACPI: Executed 1 blocks of module-level executable AML code
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.520821] ACPI: SSDT 00000000bf7980c0 00F20 (v01 DpgPmm P001Ist 00000011 INTL 20060113)
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.521247] ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.521374] ACPI: SSDT (null) 00F20 (v01 DpgPmm P001Ist 00000011 INTL 20060113)
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.521691] ACPI: Interpreter enabled
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.521748] ACPI: (supports S0 S1 S3 S4 S5)
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.521993] ACPI: Using IOAPIC for interrupt routing
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.523002] PCI: MMCONFIG at [mem 0xe0000000-0xefffffff] reserved in ACPI motherboard resources
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.554533] ACPI: No dock devices found.
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.554649] PCI: Using host bridge windows from ACPI; if necessary, use "pci=nocrs" and report a bug
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.555620] ACPI: PCI Root Bridge [PCI0] (domain 0000 [bus 00-ff])
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.588224] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Routing Table [\_SB_.PCI0._PRT]
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.588398] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Routing Table [\_SB_.PCI0.P0P1._PRT]
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.588451] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Routing Table [\_SB_.PCI0.P0P4._PRT]
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.588473] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Routing Table [\_SB_.PCI0.P0P6._PRT]
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.588492] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Routing Table [\_SB_.PCI0.P0P7._PRT]
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.588512] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Routing Table [\_SB_.PCI0.P0P8._PRT]
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.588540] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Routing Table [\_SB_.PCI0.NPE1._PRT]
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.588559] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Routing Table [\_SB_.PCI0.NPE3._PRT]
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.588579] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Routing Table [\_SB_.PCI0.NPE7._PRT]
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.588606] pci0000:00: Requesting ACPI _OSC control (0x1d)
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.588667] pci0000:00: ACPI _OSC request failed (AE_NOT_FOUND), returned control mask: 0x1d
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.588746] ACPI _OSC control for PCIe not granted, disabling ASPM
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.597661] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKA] (IRQs 3 4 6 7 10 11 12 14 *15)
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.598137] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKB] (IRQs *5)
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.598331] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKC] (IRQs 3 4 6 7 10 *11 12 14 15)
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.598804] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKD] (IRQs 3 4 6 7 *10 11 12 14 15)
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.599278] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKE] (IRQs 3 4 6 7 10 11 12 *14 15)
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.599756] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKF] (IRQs *3 4 6 7 10 11 12 14 15)
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.600230] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKG] (IRQs 3 4 6 *7 10 11 12 14 15)
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.600704] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKH] (IRQs 3 *4 6 7 10 11 12 14 15)
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.601926] PCI: Using ACPI for IRQ routing
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.624115] pnp: PnP ACPI init
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.624179] ACPI: bus type pnp registered
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.624382] pnp 00:00: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0a08 PNP0a03 (active)
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.624821] system 00:01: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0c01 (active)
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.624875] pnp 00:02: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0200 (active)
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.624911] pnp 00:03: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0b00 (active)
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.624933] pnp 00:04: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0800 (active)
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.624962] pnp 00:05: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0c04 (active)
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.625186] system 00:06: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0c02 (active)
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.625733] system 00:07: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0c02 (active)
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.625803] pnp 00:08: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0103 (active)
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.625856] pnp 00:09: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs INT0800 (active)
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.625984] system 00:0a: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0c02 (active)
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.626206] system 00:0b: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0c02 (active)
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.626256] pnp 00:0c: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0303 PNP030b (active)
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.626312] pnp 00:0d: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0f03 PNP0f13 (active)
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.626445] system 00:0e: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0c02 (active)
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.626936] system 00:0f: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0c01 (active)
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.627027] pnp: PnP ACPI: found 16 devices
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.627084] ACPI: ACPI bus type pnp unregistered
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.722086] ACPI: Power Button [PWRB]
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.722246] ACPI: Power Button [PWRF]
Dec 7 21:45:22 www kernel: [ 0.722320] ACPI: acpi_idle yielding to intel_idle
```

Answer (score 6):

The kernel is reporting that the firmware has refused to pass control of [PCIe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Express) functionality to the kernel. _OSC is an [ACPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Configuration_and_Power_Interface) control method that the kernel uses to see if the firmware (BIOS) will allow it to control PCIe [Active State Power Management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_State_Power_Management) (amongst other things).

This is just a warning message and not a bug.

Answer (score 5):

The motherboard.  More specifically, the BIOS.  It is only saying that ASPM ( power saving mode for the pcie bus when it is idle ) is being disabled as a result, so just ignore it.

Comment: That's to say,it's not important?
Because my server freezes randomly and its monitor turns to black screen. and I have to restart manually
Then I suspects other errors which I saw
kernel:udev-fallback-graphics main process terminated with status 1
kernel: init: failsafe main process killed by TERM signal
load fallback graphics devices[fail]
For this second error I reinstalled graphics card
After that the machine hasn't been down yet
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller nVidiaCorporationG98GeForce 8400 GS rev a1 prog-if 00 VGA controller
I have 2 nic cards realtech onboard,intel Whatcan be problem

Comment: @YavuzMaslak I suggest asking a new question with the exact problem.

Comment: ASPM is activated in my BIOS and I still get the error. One can overwrite it by GRUB with `pcie_aspm=force` but this is unsecure. If GRUB can do it, the kernel can do it even better. Therefore, it is a bug in the kernel.

Comment: @musbach, no, it is a bug in your bios.  Specifically it fails to provide the mandatory `OSC` ACPI method, and as a result, the kernel decides it is not safe to enable ASPM and so does not.  It very well may still work if you tell it to force it on anyhow ( or worse, appear to work but cause random data corruption from time to time ), but its default position is that this is unwise in the presence of this bios bug.

Comment: @psusi I can set ACPI 1.0, 2.0 and version 3.0. It is hard to believe that all versions are wrong. If one uses an interface, it is always a debate if the called program or the caller makes the mistake. In most cases, the specification is not precise and both are half right/wrong. Having said this, it doesn’t help because the error is still there. Since it is Intel (coretemp) we are talking about, it would be an option to fix in in the kernel.