# what is the meaning of `ACPI_OSC request failed`?

Tags: xorg, acpi, bios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [error about ACPI _OSC request failed (AE_NOT_FOUND)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86499/error-about-acpi-osc-request-failed-ae-not-found)

when i run `gksudo xdiagnose` and click on `view error` button, it shows me this error:
`pci0000:00: ACPI_OSC request failed (AE_ERROR), returned control mask: 0x1d`

what is the meaning of this error?
just to mention that i have some problems with my monitor backlight.

thanx a lot ;)

Answer (score 0):

The kernel is reporting that the firmware has refused to pass control of [PCIe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Express) functionality to the kernel. _OSC is an [ACPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Configuration_and_Power_Interface) control method that the kernel uses to see if the firmware (BIOS) will allow it to control PCIe (amongst other things).

This is just a warning message and not a bug.